# Java Servlet error in throwing exceptions for doGet( ) calling stored procedure

Tags: java, database, servlets

Anyone know how to fix the following errors

`unreported exception javax.naming.NamingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    Context context = new InitialContext();`

`Auth.java:46: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown conn = ds.getConnection();`

that I get from this java servlet?

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;

public class ABC extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
  }

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    Connection conn;
    CallableStatement cs;

    String xy = req.getParameter("xy");
    String zz = req.getParameter("zz");

    // call stored procedure
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/mypool");
    conn = ds.getConnection();
    cs = conn.prepareCall( "{call mysproc (?,?)}" );
    cs.setString(1, xy);
    cs.setString(2, zz);
    cs.execute();

    if ( conn != null ) {
      try { conn.close(); } catch ( Exception ex ) {}
      conn = null;
    }

    // Set the content type (MIME Type) of the response.
    res.setContentType("text/html");

    // Write the HTML to the response
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>my title</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h2>my header</h2>");
    out.println("my body text<br/>");
    out.println("</body>);
    out.println("</html>");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
  }

  public void destroy() {  
  }         
}
```

If I try to replace

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
```

with

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws Exception {
```

or

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException, NamingException {
```

they both produce errors saying I cannot override doGet, as overridden method does not throw Exception, or SQLException, or NamingException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`new InitialContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#constructor_detail) throws a checked exception `NamingException`, which should either be caught or the method where you are using this code should have a throws clause associated with it.

Since you are extending [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) and overriding [`doGet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method you cannot attach new checked Exception, as it is against the law of overriding in Java.

Instead place the code inside a try catch block and catch `NamingException`.

So instead of

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
```

replace this by

```
Context context = null;
try {
    context = new InitialContext();
} catch(NamingException exp){
    //Handle Exception
}
```

Similarly [`dataSource.getConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection%28%29) throws a checked exception `SQLException` which should be caught or rethrown, once again you cannot add new checked exception to your doGet method because of rules of overriding you will have to catch it explicitly.

```
try {
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/mypool");
    conn = ds.getConnection();
    cs = conn.prepareCall( "{call mysproc (?,?)}" );
    cs.setString(1, xy);
    cs.setString(2, zz);
    cs.execute();

} catch ( SQLException exp ) {
  //Handle your exception
} finally {  
  if (conn != null ) {
      try {
         conn.close(); 
      } catch(SQLException sqlExp){
         // Handle your exception     
      }
      conn = null;
    }
}
```

Rules of Overriding in Java:

[Overridden Method](http://code.google.com/p/learn-java/wiki/OverridenMethod)

- Arguments    Must not change
- Return type  Can't change except for covariant (subtype) returns
- Exceptions   Can reduce/eliminate. Must not throw new/broader checked exceptions
- Access   Must not be more restrictive. Can be less restrictive.
- Invocation   Which method to call is based on object type, at runtime time

Comment: Thanks mprabhat for being so complete in your answer. It was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  You cannot add exceptions to the overridden method's `throws` clause.

Instead, put the statements in question in a `try`/`catch` block and deal with the errors.  If nothing else, you can rethrow them as a `ServletException`.  For example:

```
Context context;
try {
    context = new InitialContext();
}
catch (NamingException e) {
    throw new ServletException(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks QuantumMechanic, the handling of exceptions was particularly useful.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the SQL code with try-catch as given by @mprabhat & @QuantumMechanic is the best way to go..

If you were wondering why can't you do

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws Exception {
```

OR

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException, NamingException {
```

.. it is because when you are overriding a method - there two important things to keep in mind..

- The overriding method can have a more liberal accessor.. example: if the super class method is declared `protected int add(...)`, you can override with `public int add(...)`, the reverse is not possible.
- The overriding method must declare the same or a sub-type of the super class's exceptions.. for example.. if the super class method is declared `public int add() throws IllegalArgumentException`, then the overriding method can have the following syntaxes.. `public int add() throws NumberFormatException`, but it cannot have a more broader syntax like `public int add() throws Exception`.

Thanks everyone for not downvoting!!